When run the eb --version give me error of the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
Full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\Users\arsalan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\eb.exe_main.py", line 4, in <module>
File "C:\Users\arsalan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\ebcore.py", line 16, in <module>
from cement.core import foundation, handler, hook
File "C:\Users\arsalan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cement\core\foundation.py", line 11, in <module>
from ..core import output, extension, arg, controller, meta, cache, mail
File "C:\Users\arsalan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cement\core\extension.py", line 8, in <module>
from imp import reload # pragma: no cover
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

I try a lot and even uninstall and reinstall the package it doesn't work.

Could you put the exact command syntax in the body of the question, delimited with some type of quotation marks? Is it "be" or "eb"?

The problem was already reported many times: https://github.com/datafolklabs/cement/issues?q=is%3Aissue+imp

https://pypi.org/project/ebcli The latest version was released in 2017. Requires Python: 2.7. Abandoned outdated package. My advice is to forget it. Is it the package you're trying? May be you want https://pypi.org/project/awscli/ ?

Module imp was deprecated since Python 3.4 and finally removed in 3.12. So you cannot use the module (and whatever depends on it) with 3.12. Use Python 3.11 or ask the authors of the packages you're trying to install to upgrade their code.

My current version of python is 3.12.2 how do I get install an deprecated or removed package even for latest python version?

You cannot until the authors update their packages. No magic wand, sorry.

depending on the license, you can likely modify the package yourself to use importlib rather than imp (3.11 doc link)

Thanks, ti7! That worked for me to get bkchem working!
